# testing in Iphone

Tags: iphone

Are SenTestingKit and OCUnit the same or are they 2 different ways to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OCUnit is a testing framework... Features of OCUnit include: SenTestingKit, a framework to help you write test cases...

So SenTestingKit is a component (part) of OCUnit.

Source: http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/